# Goto pageid if cookie is set?

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create an loginpage in my jquery mobile which sets an cookie if login = true. That part works just fine, but now I want to be able to make the user go to an specific pageid if the cookie is set using jquery. How do I do so?

I'm running this in my jquery:

```
if($.cookie("mydomain")){ 
    alert("I'm logged in");

} else {
    alert("I'm logged out");

}
```

In my index.html I have 2 data-roles, `<div data-role="page" id="page1">` and `<div data-role="page" id="page2">`.

I want to go to page1 if i'm not logged in (default) and if the cookie is set go to page2.

Hoping for help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `window.location.assign(url)` to redirect in JS:

```
var url = "";
if ($.cookie("mydomain")){ 
    url = "page2.html";
} 
else {
    url = "page1.html";
}
window.location.assign(url);
```

Alternatively, you can use `window.location.replace(url);` if you do not want the current page to appear in the browser's history.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to another page using:

```
window.location='page1';
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be window.location?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [jQuery Mobile changePage()](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html) method :

```
if ($.cookie("mydomain")){ 
    $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
} else {
    $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
}
```

[Working example here using buttons - but demos the changePage() method](http://jsfiddle.net/r4DyU/371/)